# Very simple Chrome Extension to display alert

Tags: javascript, api, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create a quick Chrome extension (complete beginner) and just want to display an alert whenever the icon is clicked, so I tried the following:

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "name": "Something",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "Woohoo",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png"
    },
    "content_scripts" : [{
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "js" : ["bgscript.js"]
    }]

}
```

**bgscript.js**

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) { 
    alert('icon clicked')
});
```

However when I click on my icon, nothing happens! Looking at the above - can anyone spot why this wouldn't work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to be notified for browser-action's `onClicked` event, you need a **[background-page](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages.html)** (or better yet **[event-page](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages.html)**), not a **[content-script](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html)**.
Change your manifest like this:

```
// Replace that:
"content_scripts" : [{...}]

// with this:
"background": {
    "persistent": false,
    "scripts": ["bgscript.js"]
}
```

---

If you want the browser-action to invoke something on a content-script, you need to communicate throught the background-page using **[Message Passing](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html)** (e.g. **[Simple one-time requests](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html#simple)**).
E.g.:

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "name": "Something",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "Woohoo",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png"
    },
    "background": {
        "persistent": false,
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
    "content_scripts" : [{
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "js" : ["content.js"]
    }]
}
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
    /* Send a message to the active tab's content script */
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, { action: 'saySomething' });
});
```

**content.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (msg) {
    /* We received a message, let's do as instructed */
    if (msg.action === 'saySomething') {
        alert('something');
    }
});
```

Comment: Ah ok - found so many threads on the net saying to use "content_scripts" which lead to my problems! Works now though, thanks very much :)

Comment: Always glad to help :) BTW, since I wasn't sure if you where trying to communicate with the background-page or with a content-script, I updated the answer to cover the second case as well.

Comment: Thanks very much for the update - looks like I've got some reading up to do, but at least you got me back on track!

Comment: Wasn't me - I upvoted you! It was a damn good answer. I think someone is just doing a few drive-by downranks. Had a few myself today :(

Comment: But why should it be my answer ? Why me ? Whyyyy ? :D